# How to extract NSString from an userdefined object?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, type-conversion

I have an object, suppose of class A, and it has a string stored in it. I want to type-cast it into `NSString` object. Basically this is what I want to achieve:

```
NSString *temp = (NSString *)[A someMEthod];

if(temp isMemberOfClass : [NSString class]) {
    dosomething
}
```

Can somebody tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check an object if it is of certain class (in runtime), use this:

```
if ([myObj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) { ... }
```

Your question isn't exactly cleat, it seems your best option is to make the "string stored in the object" be a property with the type of NSString already, so you wouldn't have to do any type casts and checks at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
id temp = [A someMethod];
if([temp isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    NSString *str = (NSString *)temp;
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your string is member variable of ClassA.

You Can make a Method in ClassA that will return NSString.

like that.

```
@interface ClassA :NSObject{

NSString *str;

}

-(NSString *)returnString{

return str;

}
```